# Which Eclipse wtp version should I use for maven?

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, maven-3, eclipse-wtp

I receive this error when I try to run the maven goal - mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=3.3.1

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin:2.8
:eclipse (default-cli) on project conference-web: Unsupported WTP version: 3.3.1
. This plugin currently supports only the following versions: 1.0 1.5 2.0 R7 non
e. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Will using version 2.0 suffice ? But should'nt the goal run successfully ?

```
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
<configuration>
    <wtpmanifest>true</wtpmanifest>
    <wtpapplicationxml>true</wtpapplicationxml>
    <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
</configuration>
```

Does'nt below image confirm I am use wtp version 3.3.1 ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the latest supported wtp version of the plugin, open the project in eclipse and in the 'problems' view right click on the warning "wtp project version to old" and choose 'quickfix.

As far as i remember the support of wtp was removed from the plugin since the maven eclipse m2eclipse plugin got more advanced. Any reasons you're not using that one?

Comment: I need the maven project to be a web app once its installed. How does m2eclipse have anything to do with this ? m2eclipse is an Eclipse plugin wheras I'm referring to a maven plugin. I dont understand your answer, but thanks

Comment: Hallo

the eclipse:eclipse plugin writes .classpath and .project files that link the dependencies directly to the local maven repository. If you add a new dependency you need to re-execute the plugin.

m2eclipse is an eclipse plugin that dynamically resolves dependencies based on the pom.xml files directly. It also comes with a pom editor and some dependency analysis capabilities.

So using m2eclipse allows the IDE to use the same configuration as maven (the pom.xml). So you dont need the eclipse:eclipse plugin anymore to run and develop projects based on maven in eclipse.

Comment: Therefore the newer WTP versions are not supported anymore by that plugin, you can work quite well using m2eclipse.