# How do you organise a Java solution into multiple projects, like in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, java, maven, architecture

I'm a .NET developer who needs to use the Java platform for a new project.

"Solutions" are a useful Visual Studio concept. How do I break my Java solution into "projects" (I guess Java packages) which have build interdependencies in the same source control repository?

We're planning to use Maven for third-party dependencies, and Scala for writing some of the libraries.

We also need to be IDE-independent.

Recommendations gratefully received!

Edit: Let us assume the solution will contain a web application, a console application, and a library written in Scala.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have set up a similar model that you can study.

By using Maven it will be as IDE-agnostic as it can. You will not have to store any specific IDE settings in your VCS, just the source code and the pom files. Each developer will launch his IDE and point to the top pom and the project should load. Local settings will be created but should be ignored when committing to the VCS.

First of all a multi module Maven project will most definitely have a very similar layout as a C# solution with its projects. The top-folder with the parent-pom will be like the solution with the shared configurations and build order etc. Then the sub-folders with the sub-poms will match the project definitions with dependencies between other projects.

`directory layout`

```
+- pom.xml
+- scala
| +- pom.xml
| +- src
|   +- main
|     +- scala
+- console
| +- pom.xml
| +- src
|   +- main
|     +- java
+- web
  +- pom.xml
  +- src
    +- main
     +- java
     +- resources
     +- webapp
       +- WEB-INF
         -- web.xml
```

`pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>Q11226363</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.9.2</scala.version>
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>scala</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>console</module>
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <!-- Inter-Module dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
                <artifactId>Q11226363-scala</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
                <version>${scala.version}</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala-tools.org</id>
            <name>Scala Tools Maven2 Repository</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

`scala/pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q11226363</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q11226363-scala</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

`console/pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q11226363</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q11226363-console</artifactId>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>Q11226363-scala</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

`web/pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>Q11226363</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>Q11226363-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>Q11226363-scala</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>webapp</finalName>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`scala/src/main/scala/com/stackoverflow/Q11226363/ScalaApp.scala`

```
/**
 * @author maba, 2012-06-28
 */
package com.stackoverflow.Q11226363

class ScalaApp {
  def helloScala():String = "Hello from Scala!"
}
```

`console/src/main/java/com/stackoverflow/Q11226363/JavaApp.java`

```
package com.stackoverflow.Q11226363;

/**
 * @author maba, 2012-06-28
 */
public class JavaApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScalaApp scalaApp = new ScalaApp();
        System.out.println("Scala says: " + scalaApp.helloScala());
    }
}
```

That has been tested by me. There can of course be some improvements to the pom files and dependencies but it is a good start.

If you look in the `web/target` you will find your `webapp.war` which will include the dependencies needed.

It is of course possible to split all these modules up and build them separately and still have dependencies between them but as I said it is a good starting point.

Comment: What an astonishingly good answer to the question. Thank you!

Comment: @PeteMontgomery Well thank you! I am glad I could assist you.

Answer (score 2):

My personal approach is to use Maven for both:

- Third-party dependencies (typically via Maven Central)
- Inter-dependencies between different projects (typically via the local repository)

This works pretty well and I believe it is IDE independent (although I've only tested it on Eclipse)

**Note:**

If you have a team working together on the same artifacts you will need some way to have a shared repository containing them, although this can be done quite simply by e.g.:

- Putting a repository on a shared file server (see: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html)
- Hosting a repository on GitHub (see: http://cemerick.com/2010/08/24/hosting-maven-repos-on-github/)

Comment: Does this mean we must run our own Maven server?

Answer (score 2):

Using [gradle](http://www.gradle.org), you would create one super-project and create your various modules as sub-projects.
From there, you can create workspace/project descriptions for the various IDEs.

Since gradle is fully compatible with Maven style repositories, @mikera's remarks on repositories are valid as well.

Comment: Would this work for, say, a Scala library, a Java console app and a Java web app in the same super-project?

Comment: I'm quite sure it would work, but I can't give you any details. Best ask the experts on the [forums](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle).

Comment: I had a play with Gradle and it's lovely, and it certainly supports multi-project builds as a first class thing. I suspect we'll move to  it when Maven becomes too much of a pain to customise!

Comment: I strongly suggest to start with gradle right away, if you have the choice. 
Painful experience teaches that there is never a good point to convert the entire build system, and it's always a tad less painful to add just another workaround.

Comment: Thanks, I would normally agree. However, in this case most of us are new to the entire Java platform, but there's a bit of familiarity with Maven on the team at least!

Answer (score 1):

Use a mulit-module (pom-packaging) Maven project at the root of your project structure to build all sources with Maven.

Then use workspaces (Eclipse) or groups (NetBeans) to display the sub-set of projects you want to work with.

Comment: I don't mind only being able to open one project / package at a time. Could you give me more info on how to do this in Maven?

Comment: Here is a tutorial: http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html

Answer (score 0):

Your C# solution is as dependent on Visual Studio as a Java solution will be dependent on its tools.

The answer also depends on packaging: JAR for desktop, WAR for web, EAR for enterprise with EJBs.

Maven makes a lot of choices for you if you decide to go in that direction (e.g. directory structure, etc.)

Eclipse and IntelliJ will both do it differently.  IntelliJ uses a module concept that I find works very well.  I prefer it over Eclipse; I'm not familiar with how it's done in that IDE now.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really see any content in this answer that wasn't already in the question...

Answer (score 0):

You actually create different projects which will be deployed as different jar files; then, using Maven, these dependencies can be added where they are needed.

Maven also brings IDE independence; there are plug-ins for different IDEs. For example with

```
mvn idea:idea
```

Maven automatically creates the project files for Intellij IDE.

Comment: The `maven-idea-plugin` is obsolete and shouldn't be used. Just open a project by pointing to the `pom.xml` file from within IntelliJ. The same for Eclipse which now uses m2e plugin instead of `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Comment: Could you provide some arguments or references?

Comment: Well I haven't downvoted you or so I just wanted to inform you that there are better ways to load maven projects into different IDEs. But for the record the [`maven-idea-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/index.html) has not been active since 2008. Regarding `mvn eclipse:eclipse` there is information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227312/which-eclipse-wtp-version-should-i-use-for-maven/9227934#comment11690275_9227934) for example.

Comment: I still haven't understood clearly the arguments; I've opened a question on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240288/maven-idea-plugin-or-eclipes-plugin .

Answer (score -1):

**Solution** is the property of Visual Studio not .Net. In future , eclipse might support solution (may be).

You can emulate the Solution idea using the **WORKSPACE** concept in Eclipse

1. Create a new workspace
2. Import all projects (make sure you check "Copy project to workspace, so that a physical copy is created)
3. Now , whenever you open this workspace, you can always see all the project.

You can also refer other projects in the workspace, using Build->Configure Build Path -> Project and Add Projects

If you want to "Exclude from Solution", you can do the same in eclipse by "Closing a Project"