# Maven IDEA plugin (or eclipse plugin)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, intellij-idea

From what I have understood, it is not the best way to open a project built with Maven in Intellij by using the idea plug-in, that is by calling:

```
mvn idea:idea
```

but by open directly the pom file (Intellij has default plug-in for Maven); the same thing, for eclipse.

Could you provide some arguments on why this is a better approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This applies equally to IntelliJ and Maven:

- changing `pom.xml` file is not reflected in your IDE, you must rebuild the project (possibly losing some configuration (?)) every time. Moreover, if any team member modifies `pom.xml`, you have to remember about rebulding your project (which will require closing and reopening it).
- additional step is required when opening new project
- IDEs have some other Maven features, e.g. both of aforementioned environemnts can show dependency graphs

Use mvn plugin as a last resort only when your IDE goes crazy and cannot figure out maven configuration correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For eclipse, the maven-eclipse plugin is not really maintained