# Importing a Java project to IntelliJ IDEA community edition

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ. What is the best (and recommend method) for importing project into IntelliJ. Is there a maven plugin for doing this?

More specially I'm interesting in importing this project. 
https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter?source=c

Thanks.

UPDATE 1 - When I try to use File -> open (the m2-pom.xml file) it just opens the xml file (as shown in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that project has a pom file named `m2-pom.xml`.  You should import that as a maven project.  Assuming it's using standard repositories, you'll immediately be able to compile the code with maven.

You can select `Open` in the menu, and then choose that file and it should load the project.

Be aware this seems to be a clojure project.  You might want to research the La Clojure plugin to see how/if it can import clojure projects with it.  It looks like the steps I gave will work, but the code may not run very easily for you without the La Clojure plugin.

Comment: I tried (open from menu and loading the m2-pom.xml file) before posting the question here. But it opens the m2-pom.xml file (please see the updated screen shot in the question above)

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta Interesting, I think it doesn't know it's a maven file because the name is different.  Could you try renaming it to `pom.xml` then try again?

Comment: I renamed m2-pom.xml to pom.xml it works. I don't even have the classpath issue that I had with mvn idea:idea option.

Answer (score 1):

You could either import the Maven project inside of IntelliJ (`File` -> `Import Project...`), or you could simply use the [Maven IDEA plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-idea-plugin/). All you do is execute `mvn idea:idea` inside of the Maven directory, and a project file will be generated. This file may be opened as a project inside of IntelliJ.

**EDIT**: @maba [warns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16849289/importing-a-java-project-to-intellij-idea-community-edition/16849541?noredirect=1#comment24301363_16849541) *not* to use the Maven IntelliJ plugin.

Comment: Nice trick, I didn't know about IDEA plugin or `mvn idea:idea`

Comment: I tried this and I was able to import the project but it has a bunch of compile errors (symbol not found). Is there is an easy way to check what jars are in the classpath and modify the classpath as well ?

Comment: @SoumyaSimanta Is it just an issue with dependencies? You can ensure that all of your dependencies are either present in the repositories provided in your pom.xml, or installed in your local repository. To install a dependency, just execute `mvn install` in that project's Maven directory.

Comment: @rmsy - thanks. I'll look into this. But I tried using tieTYT's approach below and renamed my m2-pom.xml to pom.xml and everything works now.

Comment: Using mvn idea:idea is a **bad** suggestion. The plugin hasn't been updated since 2008 and should really not be used. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240288/maven-idea-plugin-or-eclipes-plugin

Comment: @maba I don't really see what that user is trying to say... If he's mentioning that the plugin shouldn't be used because changes aren't automatically reflected, IntelliJ has a feature to do just that (Maven auto-refresh). Also, I don't really see *why* the plugin would need to be updated, unless there's a drastic change in Maven or IntelliJ. All the plugin does is add the modules; IntelliJ handles the rest of the Maven integration.

Comment: There are *major* changes in IntelliJ since 2008. One of them is that the project structure changed from `.ipr` file based to `.idea` folder based. It is **5** years ago that plugin was latest updated. Believe me, that plugin should **not** be used. Point to the `pom.xml` and let IntelliJ do what it knows best (setting up it's own project structure).